# Why won't Skype open or install properly on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation, skype

I have attempted to install Skype using the skype website for Ubuntu 12.04, and it says that I have to open it with the software centre, so when I click on the file it says error.

I then followed instructions on how to install it using the terminal, which came up with errors. Although the skype application button came up when I searched the computer, when I clicked on it nothing came up.

The computer I'm using is a compaq presario F500.

Any suggestions as to why skype won't work or install?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please paste or type the error that you obtained in both the cases?

Answer (score 0):

Open Ubuntu software Center, by clicking on the icon on the unity bar.

[image]

Once it opens, search for Skype, and click on Use This Source.

[image]

Wait a while, and then click on Install

[image]

Wait for the installation to finish, search for Skype in Dash, click on the icon and enjoy.

[image]